# Using debounce.js

Tags: 8, javascript

I see that debounce.js is included in the Drupal 8 core (core/misc/debounce) and I'd like to leverage it for a slider (Slick Slider) that will only be called on mobile only. While I think the function I've created is correct, I'm not sure how to access the debounce function in my js file. So, for example, in `global.js` I have the following:

```
(function ($, Drupal, debounce) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.mobileSlider = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var viewportChange = debounce(function() {
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        if (bodyWidth <= 768) {
          // enable slider
        }
        else{
          // destroy slider
        }
      }, 250);
      window.addEventListener('resize', viewportChange);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, Drupal.debounce);
```

I also see that when I'm logged in I see debounce.js is called but when I view the site when not logged in I don't see debounce called despite listing it as a dependency in libraries.yml

```
global-scripts:
  js:
    js/global.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/misc/debounce.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the dependency of your JavaScript in the wrong way. It's core/drupal.debounce, as the System module uses in [system.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.libraries.yml/8.4.x).

```
drupal.system.modules:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/system.modules.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.debounce
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal.announce
```

What you use as dependency is the machine name of the library that, as visible in [core.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.libraries.yml/8.4.x), is drupal.debounce.

```
drupal.debounce:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    misc/debounce.js: {}
  dependencies:
    # @todo Remove Drupal dependency.
    - core/drupal
```

The *core/* appended first means it's the *drupal.debounce* library defined in the core.libraries.yml file.